# How to understand the construct "Was sind das bloß für Leute"?

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm so confused here. Both "Was" and "das" are singular, so why the plural "sind"? I don't know which of "Was" or "das" is the subject of the sentence in the first place.

> **Was sind das bloß für Leute**, die es gut finden, dass ihre Kinder andere verprügeln? Ich würde einen riesigen Schrecken kriegen, sollte mein Kind sich in einer Schlägerbande befinden. Hilfe.

Comment: *Leute* is Plural, so let's replace it with *ein Mensch* (Singular): "Was ist das bloß für ein Mensch, der es gut findet, dass seine Kinder andere verprügeln?"

Comment: In case that "für" is confusing to someone, "was sind das [ADJ] arme Leute" or "Was ein [Attributive Noun] Führertyp er ist" (cp. "What a nice guy") works as well, just lacking the inquisitive tone of the rhetoric question.

Answer (score 7):

Leute ist ein Plural, für den es keinen Singular gibt - ein seltener Fall. "Die Leute gehen aus." Weil *Leute* Plural ist, ist *gehen* im Plural. Genauso bei "Die Leute sind doof".

Was und das sind kein Singular. Was sowieso nicht.

- Was ist das für eine Schraube?
- Was sind das für Schrauben?

Das Auto, das Boot, die Autos, die Boote - da wäre *das* ein bestimmter Artikel, Singular, sächlich.

> Ich nehme noch ein Glas, das heißt, ich bin noch durstig.

Hier ist *das* ein Verweiswort (Verweiswort ist kein Fachterminus), das auf etwas anderes hinweist, hier auf Leute, die ein bestimmtes Verhalten gezeigt haben, kein bestimmter Artikel.

*The Awful Language* hat in seinem Beispielsatz schön gezeigt, dass sich im Singular nur Verb und Subjekt ändern, nicht *was* und *das*:

> Was ist das für ein Vater, (der es gut findet, dass ...)
>
> Was ist das für eine Mutter, (die es gut findet, dass ...)

Zum Subjekt:

Der Satz:

> Was sind das (bloß) für Leute!

könnte auch als Ausruf alleine stehen, etwa wenn Sprecher und Hörer zusammenstehen und auf die Szene mit diesen Leuten blicken. Das Verb ist offensichtlich **sind**. Das Subjekt ist diese **Leute**.

Comment: "sollte mein Kind sich in einer Schlägerbande befinden" Can I ask? Is this meaning "my child gets tangled with bad boys unwillingly" or "my child hangs around with bad boys willingly, of his own free will"?

Comment: *was* ist sehr wohl ein Singular (kann einer sein). Zufällig ist der Plural von *was* eben auch *was* - Deswegen kann man aber noch lange nicht sagen, es wäre nicht eins von beidem. (http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-was_fuer.html)

Comment: English has a different opinion about singular *what*, and subject position, eg. in "what I want *is* book*s*", though the validity of that grammar is, well, besides the point.

Answer (score 0):

The original sentence - before rearrangement - would be 'Was fuer Leute sind das bloss?'

Then 'was fuer Leute' is the noun phrase that acts as subject of the sentence analogous to 'what kind of people'.

The confusion stems from the verb 'sein'. Logically, if A=B then B=A: 'Der Junge is gross. Gross ist der Junge.'

But what to do if A and B differ in number? Also in English many people go with the plural when speaking about a group of people. As in 'A group of us is/are going to the theatre this evening.' https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39838/is-group-singular-or-plural

'das' can be thought of short for 'das da drueben' and has a meaning analogous to 'them over there'. It creates more distance from the speaker. It is not the subject.

Comment: Ich erhebe Widerspruch: Die Formulierung mit "für" ist sehr eigenartig und nicht ohne sicheren historischen Beleg auf die eine oder andere Satzbauweise zurückzuführen.