# Was für ein "für" ist das?

Tags: etymology, idiom

Kann es eventuell möglich sein, dass dieses komische "für" in "Was für ein armer Kerl" irgendwie redundant weil eigentlich von Alt-Hochdeutschem "fao, fō, fōh" ist?

S. En. [poor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poor) "ärmlich", die Wurzel und deren AHD-Ableitung.

Zum Vergleich: Englisch kennt bloß "what a poor guy" und dies überlebt in gleicher Syntax auch im Deutschen "was ein Unsinn", "so ein armer Kerl". Ich möchte nicht unbelegt behaupten, *Armut* sei noch besonders stark mit dem Idiom verknüpft, oder es je gewesen. Ich wüsste nicht, wie das zu belegen sein soll. Die hier fragliche Herleitung setzt es aber fast vorraus. Zumindest ist "was für" häufig negativ besetzt, "Was für Leute das sind" (s. [die Frage letztens dazu](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53269/)). "was für eine tolle Idee" ist zudem meist sarkastisch (so wie *toll* auch in *Tollwut* oder *Tollhaus* auftritt).

Comment: Verstehe ich das richtig: Du möchtest wissen, ob sich *für* und *arm* auf eine gemeinsame Alt-Hochdeutsche Wurzel "fao, fō, fōh"  zurückführen lässt? Wenn Dich frz. *pour* und engl. *poor* darauf gebracht haben, hast Du schon geprüft, ob diese eine etymologische Verwandtschaft zum dt. *arm* haben?

Comment: Wäre es möglich, die Frage so zu strukturieren, dass Problemstellung & Frage klar erkennbar sind, sowie die bisherige Recherche/ Vermutung? Bisher liest es sich für mich mehr wie ein Gedankenschnipsel, weniger wie eine klar erkennbare Frage. Danke.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Es könnte doch klarer nicht sein. Du rauchst spät in der Nacht eine Haschischzigarette. Dir kommt die Ähnlichkeit von frz. *pour* und engl. *poor* in den Sinn. *Was für ein armer Kerl* enthält sowohl *für* als auch *arm*. Aber was wäre, wenn *für* gar nicht *für* bedeuten würde, sondern *arm*? Dann wäre es ja redundant! Also im [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/fawaz) geblättert und ahd. *fō* (eigentlich *einige, wenige* aber *arm* paßt vielleicht auch) gefunden. Fertig! Etymologisch heißt es *Was arm ein armer Kerl*!

Comment: Die Frage steht klar und deutlich am Anfang. Umformuliert: *Geht die Phrase "was für ein" auf AHD "foa" zurück?* @DavidVogt ja, in etwa, aber die Suche begann mit der Frage um die eigenartige Konstruktion von *was für*, die hier auch häufiger auftaucht. *Für* mit "p-r" zu vergleichen ist etymologisch sinnvoll. Der denn noch fehlende etablierte momentane Zusammenhang zwischen "poor" und "[was] für" ist die Crux. Es wäre denkbar, dass etwa plural "foa arme" eine kolokation war, die sich, als *foa* in vergessenheit geriet, etwas paradox entwickelte. ...

Comment: Eine genaue Konotation oder Ursprungsform bleibt fraglich. Die dritte Bedeutung im verlinkten Eintrag zu "poor" nennt "expressing pitty". *bemitleidenswerte arme Kerle* ist soweit vergleichbar.

Comment: Vgl auch *armer kleiner Junge*.

Answer (score 6):

### für

- Mittelhochdeutsch: **vür**
- Althochdeutsch: **furi**

Verwandt mit altisländisch **fyr** und auch eng verwandt mit dem deutschen Wort **vor** und der deutschen Vorsilbe **ver-**

### vor

- Mittelhochdeutsch: **vor**
- Althochdeutsch: **fora**
- Gotisch: **faúr, faúra**
- Altenglisch: **for**

### ver-

- Mittelhochdeutsch: **ver-**
- Althochdeutsch: **fir-**
- Gotisch: **fair-, faúr-, fra-**

Auch verwandt mit lateinisch **per-, por-, pro-** und altgriechisch **peri-, par-, pro-**

All dem liegen die indogermanischen Wurzeln **per-, peri- pr-** und **pro-** zugrunde.

---

### arm

- Mittelhochdeutsch: **arm**
- Althochdeutsch: **arm**

Verwandt mit Gotisch **arms** und altenglisch **arm.**

Die indogermanische Wurzel ist **ar, arə**

---

### engl. poor

- Altfranzösisch: **poure**
- Lateinisch: **pauper**

Geht zurück auf **pau** (wenig) und **parare** (produzieren, hervorbringen).

---

Die beiden deutschen Wörter **für** und **arm** und das englische Wort **poor** sind also in keiner Weise miteinander verwandt.

---

### Was für ein(e)

Die fest Wortfügung *»was für ein(e)«* ist ein Interrogativpronomen und bedeutet

> welch, welche, welches, welchen
>
> Was für ein Kleid soll ich heute anziehen?
>   Welches Kleid soll ich heute anziehen?

In Aussagesätzen wird damit Erstaunen ausgedrückt:

> Was für eine großartige Leistung!
>   Welch großartige Leistung!

Eine negative Konnotation ist damit nicht verbunden, sie entsteht erst durch explizit negative Verwendung:

> Was für ein Idiot!
>   Welch Idiot!

Comment: Die Schlussfolgerung zur fehlenden Verwandtschaft ist ein Kurzschluss, der auf einer sehr engen Bedeutung von etymologischer Verwandschaft beruht, der hier gar nicht in Frage stand und horizontale übertragung außer Acht lässt. Ein Indogermanischer Vergleich wäre nur angebracht, wenn auch "was für" eine Entsprechung hat. Zudem war die Frage vorrangig nur auf \*peh2w- und \*p-r- bezogen. De. "ver-" hat ca. drei unterschiedliche Bedeutungen und etymologien--man spricht von Divergenz. Davon spreche ich auch hier. La *puer* ist ungeklärt, laut V. V. Ivanov eventual über ...

Comment: ... Etruskisch mit Hurrisch, Ugaritisch etc. "Diener, Sklave" verbunden. *pauper* "arm", soweit von \*peh2w- "klein, wenig", passt gut zu *puer*, "Junge", das aber eben auch "Sklave" gedeutet wird. Es passt aber auch zu *arm*, soweit mit En *orphan* "Waisenkind" verglichen, und ebenso *Arbeit* zu *parare*, das ... moment mal ... das bei en.WT eben doch von *pro* hergeleitet wird!?!

Comment: 2. Der eigentliche Kern der Antwort, der Vergleich zu *welch'* und der rhetorischen Frage, ist hilfreiche, doch synchronisch, so nicht zufriedenstellend. En *what for* "wofür, wozu" suggeriert ein älteres Paradigma (welches *welch* nicht zeigt?), während *wofür* eher obliqu *welch[-em]* ist. *welche'* dagegen erscheint als Aorist ohne Flektion (nicht etwa Ellipse, behaupte ich mal kühn), was auch wieder auf ältere Herkunft hindeutet. So oder so sehe ich es lapidar gesagt nicht als erwiesen, das Frage-Konstrukt sei dem Relativpronom-Konstrukt vorrausgegangen, oder ob *welche* nur analog folgte.

Comment: Es wäre hilfreicher gewesen eine klare Frage zu stellen. Stattdessen jetzt an meiner Antwort herumzumäkeln finde ich nicht ok. Stelle präzisere Fragen, dann wirst du auch passendere Antworten bekommen.

Comment: Eine "klare Frage" ist doch ein Widerspruch in sich. Eine Frage ist im Prinzip eine Aussage, die in Zweifel steht, und der Zweifel soll begründet ausgeräumt werden (manchmal reicht Authorität als Begründung, etwa in einer Frage um Erlaubnis). Hätte ich "die letzte Frage dazu" früher verlinkt, hättest du dir deine Mühe sparen können, die wenig fundierte Antwort zu wiederholen; Das tut mir leid. Meine Aussage hier, die hier Zweifel steht, würde ich dort wohl als Antwort gegeben, wenn die Aussage nicht selbst so unspezifisch wäre wie das Untersuchungsobjekt, "was für eine Antwort".

Comment: Nein, eine klare Frage ist kein Widerspruch in sich. "Mit wem warst Du gestern einen Kaffee trinken?" ist eine klare Frage. Auch im Hinblick auf andere Posts von Ihnen würde ich etwas weniger Wirrheit begrüßenswert finden.

Comment: @infinitezero die Frage ist weniger wage, aber ebenso mutmaßend. Wieso will der Fragesteller das wissen (Eifersucht), was geht ihn das an (nichts), wie genau will er, falls die Person ihm nicht bekannt ist, die Antwort (Freundschaft), weshalb ist *mit wem* überhaupt dativ (Finnisch hat einen eigenen Fall für Begleitung), und was bedeutet es im sozialen Kontext einen Kaf-feh zu trinken und wie umschreibe ich die Antwort um eben darauf nicht einzugehen? Oh ich weiß, ich stelle mich ahnungslos. Kaffe, welcher Kaffe? Ich dachte es ginge hier um Sprache.

Comment: Die Intention des Fragestellers ist doch vollkommen egal? Die Frage ist präzise gestellt. Warum die Frage in einem speziellen Kasus steht ist komplett irrelevant und im Finnischen gibt es dafür auch keinen extra Fall, sondern man nimmt den Genitiv: "Kenen kanssa joit kahvia eilen?" Ihre Entscheidung wie sie die Frage beantworten und ob die die Frage überhaupt beantworten ist auch gewissermaßen unabhängig vom Präzisionsgrad der Frage. Langsam vermute ich hier Trollerei.